# Decorators in PyMC

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, pymc, mcmc

I have three question regarding decorators which I am not able to find answer to :

Q1)What do the arguments to decorators in PyMC (@Deterministic, @Stochastic) denote ?

Q2)

```
@pymc.stochastic(dtype=int)
def switchpoint(value=10, t_l=0, t_h=110):
    def logp(value, t_l, t_h):
        if value > t_h or value < t_l:
            return -np.inf
        else:
            return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)
    def random(t_l, t_h):
        from numpy.random import random
        return np.round( (t_l - t_h) * random() ) + t_l
```

1)print switchpoint.logp            *#prints log-probability as expected*

2)print switchpoint.random          *#does not generate the random number*

3)print switchpoint.random()        *# generates a random number*

4)print switchpoint.logp()          *#error*

**If 2 did not work and 3 worked then 1 should not have worked and instaed 4 should have worked (which is opposite of what I observed). Can someone explain what is going on ?**

Q3)

```
@pymc.stochastic(dtype=int)
def switchpoint(value=1900, t_l=1851, t_h=1962):
    if value > t_h or value < t_l:
        # Invalid values
        return -np.inf
    else:
        # Uniform log-likelihood
        return -np.log(t_h - t_l + 1)
```

**Here it is not specified that it is `logp` still if I type `switchpoint.logp`, this piece of code is executed ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1) The meaning of all the arguments to stochastic is documented [here](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#the-stochastic-class). The arguments to deterministic are the same, plus the additional ones documented [here](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#the-deterministic-class).

Q2) The difference in behavior is that there is some magic inside PyMC that actually executes the `switchpoint.logp` function and turns it into a Python [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), while `switchpoint.random` doesn't get this treatment, and is kept as a function.

If you're curious about what's actually going on, here's some of the relevant the [source](https://github.com/matthew-brett/pymc/blob/master/pymc/PyMCObjects.py#L265):

```
def get_logp(self):
    if self.verbose > 1:
        print '\t' + self.__name__ + ': log-probability accessed.'
    logp = self._logp.get()
    if self.verbose > 1:
        print '\t' + self.__name__ + ': Returning log-probability ', logp

    try:
        logp = float(logp)
    except:
        raise TypeError, self.__name__ + ': computed log-probability ' + str(logp) + ' cannot be cast to float'

    if logp != logp:
        raise ValueError, self.__name__ + ': computed log-probability is NaN'

    # Check if the value is smaller than a double precision infinity:
    if logp <= d_neg_inf:
        if self.verbose > 0:
            raise ZeroProbability, self.errmsg + ": %s" %self._parents.value
        else:
            raise ZeroProbability, self.errmsg

    return logp

def set_logp(self,value):
    raise AttributeError, 'Potential '+self.__name__+'\'s log-probability cannot be set.'

logp = property(fget = get_logp, fset=set_logp, doc="Self's log-probability value conditional on parents.")
```

There's some other stuff going on there, like during the `logp` function into something called a [`LazyFunction`](https://github.com/matthew-brett/pymc/blob/master/pymc/LazyFunction.pyx#L49), but that's the basic idea.

Q3) The `stochastic` decorator has some (more) magic in it that uses code introspection to determine if `random` and `logp` sub functions are defined inside `switchpoint`. If they are, it uses the `logp` sub-function to compute `logp`, if not, it just uses `switchpoint` itself. That source code for that is [here](https://github.com/matthew-brett/pymc/blob/master/pymc/InstantiationDecorators.py#L23):

```
# This gets used by stochastic to check for long-format logp and random:
if probe:
    # Define global tracing function (I assume this is for debugging??)
    # No, it's to get out the logp and random functions, if they're in there.
    def probeFunc(frame, event, arg):
        if event == 'return':
            locals = frame.f_locals
            kwds.update(dict((k,locals.get(k)) for k in keys))
            sys.settrace(None)
        return probeFunc

    sys.settrace(probeFunc)

    # Get the functions logp and random (complete interface).
    # Disable special methods to prevent the formation of a hurricane of Deterministics
    cur_status = check_special_methods()
    disable_special_methods()
    try:
        __func__()
    except:
        if 'logp' in keys:
            kwds['logp']=__func__
        else:
            kwds['eval'] =__func__
    # Reenable special methods.
    if cur_status:
        enable_special_methods()

for key in keys:
    if not kwds.has_key(key):
        kwds[key] = None

for key in ['logp', 'eval']:
    if key in keys:
        if kwds[key] is None:
            kwds[key] = __func__
```

Again, there's some more stuff going on, and it's fairly complicated, but that's the basic idea.